# Dangers of a Grounding Conductor

Tags: electrical

I recently moved into a new apartment and I have a dog that roams the space freely, I was wondering if it was at all dangerous if he were to touch this grounding conductor from the electricity meters?[image][image]

Comment: No, but that looks like an strange setup.

Comment: Probably OK, and yes indeed strange, but if you are worried about it then give it a touch with your finger.  Feel anything?  If it were mine I would sure make sure the connections are tight, just to be sure.  The ground rod itself might be fine but you don't know what a disconnected ground wires might have on it, from inside.  Safest if they are secured so they can't come loose.  Can you see the other end of the green wire(s)?

Comment: What County is this located in?

Answer (score 1):

The copper rod looks like a grounding conductor, typically located outdoors amd pounded 8 feet into the earth.

In some juristictions newer code allows (or even prefers) the rebar frame within the foundation to be used as a source of ground instead; this conductor could be connected to that.

No current should pass through any grounding conductors under normal circumstances, but if there is a problem they can carry full line voltage, and current up to the limit of the breaker or fuse protecting the problem circuit.

Comment: This would be considered a grounding electrode and as a matter of code it was not fully driven unless tied or welded to some rebar. The only time there should be any possible hazardous voltage on this would be during a lighting strike or a extreme electrical failure, if there are boot leg grounds, it is bonded to the copper pipe in the photo that is also a good electrode if in contact with earth for 10'.

Answer (score 0):

Animals are more sensitive to miniscule stray voltages.  Farmers have a serious problem, for example, with livestock and stray voltages from the power company.

While there should not be a significant amount of voltage to cause shock,  voltage is going to be in the ground at all times  ~<5 volts, do to what is referred to as NEV (neutral to earth voltage).  This isn't generally a danger, however, in rare cases some freak accidents can occur especially in pools, etc.